# OpenCV: How to stitch two images with different tones?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I encounter a tricky problem in my Computer Vision project. It requires to match and stitch two images taken in different eras:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the second image is almost black and white, which has various tones compared to the first image. How is it possible to match them?

I have implemented a SIFT feature descriptor, and it does work for finding feature points. I tried using SSD and ratio test matching, none of them worked well for this image pair. One possible approach I thought is to consider the general shape formed by all feature points in an image since the shapes of both buildings look similar. Should I use other feature descriptors to handle it?

Another problem is blending, after calculating the corresponding homography and projecting image 2 to image 1, it is difficult to do the blending, because there is significant tone conflict.

Can anyone provide some solutions? Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to stitch them? There are techniques like seamless blending and pyramid blending, histogram equalization, image to image translation, etc. but all techniques have limits. What would ge your desired result after blending those two images?

Comment: @Micka Stitching seems like impossible, and I think that as well, but this is the requirement of my project, I don't know why my professor required that. I know those blending techniques, but it is difficult to get an ideal result for blending a color image and a black and white image.

Comment: did you try histogram equalization to make the images more conparable? Is it an assignment or a project?

Comment: @Micka Histogram equalization does make them comparable, still doesn't match well by using SSD or ratio matching. Image 2 contains noise, and I am not sure denoising is necessary. This is the final project.